# Select element not working inside nested divs

Tags: html, css

My HTML is

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3">
        <div id="div4">
            <select><several options></select>
        </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `div`s are nested and the `select` element won't work. I am using CSS in an external file, but wanted to ask if this HTML layout, by itself, will cause problems. My understanding is that for IE6/7 it can cause `z-index` issues, but I am using Chrome.

If anyone wants to take the time to review the CSS I will happily post it, but wanted to first see if this is answerable on its own.

Edit

Here is the CSS. Note, div#2 is a semi-transparent background.  The other divs are supposed to be positioned over top of it.

```
#div1{
width:100%;
height:8em;
position:relative;
margin-top:3em;
margin-bottom:3em;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:black;
border-radius:4px;
z-index:10;

#div2{
width:80%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
margin-top:5%;
left:0%;
background-image:url(images/calendar_original.png);
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
opacity:0.2;
z-index:1;
}

#div3{
width:100%;
heigh:40%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:1em;
padding-left:1.5%;
z-index:13;
}

#div4{
height:4em;
width:44%;
float:left;
font-family:verdana, Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:medium;
font-weight:bold;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:black;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:14;}

select{
height:1em;
color:black;
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:large;
font-weight:bold;
width:150%;
padding-left:0.5em;
z-index:15;}
```

Comment: Ummm... yeah, please post your select statement as well. This shouldn't be affected.

Comment: HTML looks good..Can u post the CSS...

Comment: what do you end up seeing?  What CSS is assigned to the divs?  What behavior do you observe?  There is nothing inherently wrong with your html assuming you have omitted the proper `<option>` elements.

Comment: Please post your CSS in order to further investigate

Comment: nested divs will have no affect on select statements.

Comment: @cybernate CSS posted if anyone gets a chance to investigate.

Comment: @robertsmith Works fine for me @ http://jsfiddle.net/GJve6/

Comment: @cybernate OK.  Thanks for looking and trying.  Will see what else I can figure out.  I just tried removing the overflow:hidden from the box and it seems to work again.  I had that setting in there because I was trying to get clever (probably too clever) in styling my select statements to hide the arrow.  Thanks again.

Comment: @robert smith: so, does it work, finally? You still may have the </h2> tag too much (see answer below)...

Answer (score 0):

Please, post all your html. Often, it also happens to me, I don't see small things and only one character missing or at the wrong place can lead to errors.

So, first your **HTML code has one `</div>` (closed div) too much**, if this is all of your code. Probably, you don't want it to be after the `<div id="div2">`?

Furthermore, what are ? If the select does not work (in all browsers) it may likely be, that maybe a " (quote) or a / (slash) or sth small like this is missing or you e.g. wrote  instead of  etc. (Believe me, I had already experts who finally found I wrote maibox instead of mailbox etc.)

Depending on what you mean with: "is not working" (that is generally never a great description of an error). What does not work? You don't see the select or you cannot open it? Or the options are not (completely) shown?

I personally don't think it is connected to any CSS or nested div issue, but rather to some code within your select/option tags you have not completely posted.

Furthermore, just a side note: if you use Chrome, still many users use different browsers, so I suppose you want your code to be clean and working right in most all of them, right? ;)

**EDIT**: one thing, that can actually cause troubles with your select is that you assign the width of your divs with % values. You should know how this works: each element assumes 100% is the width of the element it is located in. So, div4 has 44% width of div3, and your select now has 150% of 44% of 100% of 80% of 100%. However, 150% is the magic number, so depending on the overflow, your select can be cut at 100% and the right 50% could possibly not shown.

In addition, if you already use a png as background image, do you really need the opacity on div2?